# What is causing this error while installing rubinius under rvm?

Tags: ruby, rvm, rubinius

I seem to be unable to install the latest rubinius under rvm (rvm seems to work fine and other rubies can be installed without problems). The error logs are as follows:

```
rbx-2.2.9 - #compiling - please wait
Error running '/home/michael/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.2@rubinius/rake install --trace',
showing last 15 lines of /home/michael/.rvm/log/1403116832_rbx-2.2.9/rake.log
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rubinius/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rubinius/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rubinius/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rubinius/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rubinius/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rubinius/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rubinius/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rubinius/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rubinius/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rubinius/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rubinius/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rubinius/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rubinius/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rubinius/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => install => build:build => build:llvm
```

Does anyone have any idea what this might be? am I missing something obvious? The command I am trying to run is simply:

```
rvm install rbx
```

Since it may be relevant there is an additional warning line earlier:

```
No binary rubies available for: arch/libc-2.19/x86_64/rbx-2.2.9.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
```

which seems to just say that it is compiling from source (which shouldn't be a problem afaik). System is arch linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered this question with help from mereghost on [this github issue](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2942#issuecomment-49334237).

The problem is that rvm installs rubinius with it's own `llvm` version using the `--skip-system` flag. This version of llvm has known issues running with python3 which is the default on arch linux. In order to get around this you can override this option by passing your own command line options or passing none like so:

```
rvm install rubinius --
```

see [here](https://rvm.io/rubies/installing) for details on using the command line options.